# How to estimate an SUR model in R with fixed effects and clustered standard errors?

Tags: econometrics, regression, stata, r

I want to estimate an SUR (Seemingly Unrelated Regressions) model.

I tried using `systemfit` and its wrapper `Zelig`. But I am not able to understand how to specify factors to be projected out (i.e., add fixed effects) and cluster the standard errors, like we do in `felm()`.

What I have tried :

I am adding a data sample from my data:

```
Y_var1 <- c(0.45, 0.40, 0.30, 0.40, 0.15, 0.35, 0.50, 0.55, 0.10, 0.15, 0.30, 0.10)
Y_var2 <- c(0.40, 0.25, 0.45, 0.30, 0.35, 0.25, 0.15, 0.25, 0.35, 0.30, 0.20, 0.15)
X_var1 <- c(0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)
X_var2 <- c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
X_var3 <- c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1)
X_var4 <- c(0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 0.20, 0.20, 0.20, 0.22, 0.22, 0.22, 0.24, 0.24, 0.24)
X_var5 <- c(0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02)
X_var6 <- c(-0.25, -0.25, -0.25, 1.30, 1.30, 1.30, 1.80, 1.80, 1.80, 2.25, 2.25, 2.25)
X_var7 <- c(1000, 1000, 1000, 1500, 1500, 1500, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2500, 2500, 2500)
X_var8 <- c('ABC', 'ABC', 'ABC', 'MNO', 'MNO', 'MNO', 'DEF', 'DEF', 'DEF', 'XYZ', 'XYZ', 'XYZ')
X_var9 <- c(2000, 2010, 2020, 2000, 2010, 2020, 2000, 2010, 2020, 2000, 2010, 2020)

sample_data <- data.frame(Y_var1, Y_var2, X_var1, X_var2, X_var3, X_var4, X_var5, X_var6, X_var7, X_var8, X_var9)

sample_data$X_var8_Num <- as.numeric(as.factor(sample_data$X_var8))

library(systemfit)
formula <- list(mu1 = Y_var1 ~ X_var1*X_var3 + X_var2*X_var3 + X_var4 + X_var5 + X_var6 + log(X_var7), 
                mu2 = Y_var2 ~ X_var1*X_var3 + X_var2*X_var3 + X_var4 + X_var5 + X_var6 + log(X_var7))

fitsur <- systemfit(formula = formula, data=sample_data, method = "SUR")
fitols <- systemfit(formula = formula, data=sample_data, method = "OLS")
```

However, what I am interested in is estimating the above formula using SUR, with `X_var8` and `X_var9` fixed effects and standard errors clustered at `X_var8` level.

Using the below to estimate fixed effects results in an error in the actual data.

```
formula1 <- list(mu1 = Y_var1 ~ X_var1*X_var3 + X_var2*X_var3 + X_var4 + X_var5 + X_var6 + log(X_var7) + factor(X_var8_Num) + factor(X_var9), 
                mu2 = Y_var2 ~ X_var1*X_var3 + X_var2*X_var3 + X_var4 + X_var5 + X_var6 + log(X_var7) + factor(X_var8_Num) + factor(X_var9))

fitsur <- systemfit(formula = formula1, data=sample_data, method = "SUR")
fitols <- systemfit(formula = formula1, data=sample_data, method = "OLS")
```

```
Error in LU.dgC(a) : cs_lu(A) failed: near-singular A (or out of memory)
```

If we use `felm()`, the specification is

```
felm(mu1 = Y_var1 ~ X_var1*X_var3 + X_var2*X_var3 + X_var4 + X_var5 + X_var6 + log(X_var7) | X_var8 + X_var9 | 0 | X_var8)
```

However, as my standard errors are correlated across equations as my Y variables are related, I need to use this felm specification in SUR.

Any help would be much appreciated. If this is something that can be done with Stata, then I am happy to switch (facing the same issue with sureg()). Thank You!

Comment: Have you solved this problem?

Comment: For my case, all the regressors were same across equations, so SUR and OLS give same results.

Comment: Good for you. Equations in my case also share the same regressors, but the dependent variables are count data. I read from King (1989) that when the dependent variables are count data, there are still efficiency gains to using SUR even when the regressors are the same. But I have not figured out how to estimate a SUR with count data as dependent variables plus two-way fixed-effects and clustered standard error. Would appreciate it if you happen to know a way of doing it correctly.